# Tkinter.StringVar() throws an exception

Tags: python, tkinter

I have python `2.7.2-4` (Archlinux), and from

```
import Tkinter
Tkinter.StringVar()
```

results

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/foo.py", line 3, in <module>
    foo = Tkinter.StringVar()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 251, in __init__
    Variable.__init__(self, master, value, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 182, in __init__
    self._tk = master.tk
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tk'
Exception AttributeError: "StringVar instance has no attribute '_tk'" in <bound method StringVar.__del__ of <Tkinter.StringVar instance at 0x1815710>> ignored
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `tk.Tk()` before `tk.StringVar()`:

```
import Tkinter as tk

root=tk.Tk()    
tk.StringVar()
```